# NSDateFormat buggy?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have the following code:

```
NSDateFormatter * df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"];
date1 = [df dateFromString:@"2010-08-12 08:00:00"];
```

works as a charm, however when it is above 12:00:00, such as 23:00:00 the returned NSDate is null.
Am I being stupid?

Comment: No you're not being stupid! Haha. I think it's funny how we apologize in advance of some jerk trashing us for a simple mistake. I actually work with some really experienced dudes who pawn off date conversions because they can be so finicky.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use **HH** instead of **hh** to represent 24-hr format

```
[df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
```

Comment: so does mm needs to be MM as well?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a capital HH for military time, hh is for AM/PM

Answer (score 0):

**Change your `hh` to `HH`.**

I assume the format string is not correct for your format.

Looking at the strings that can be supplied to `setDateFormat`, the Apple doc points to spec http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-10.html#Date_Format_Patterns.

```
hour
h   1..2    11  Hour [1-12].
H   1..2    13  Hour [0-23].
```